# Text fields in UIAlertViewController with rounded rect border style. (Swift)

Tags: swift, ios8, xcode6, uialertview

I have no problem adding text fields to an UIAlertController but I find these text fields to be hideous. Does anyone know how to make them more appealing?

My code to add a text field:

```
let pincodeAlert:UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: alertTitle, message: "Enter your passcode", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
pincodeAlert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler({ (pinCodeTextField:UITextField!) -> Void in
            pinCodeTextField.placeholder = "Password"
            pinCodeTextField.secureTextEntry = true
pincodeAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil}))
pincodeAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
            //do some other stuff here...
        }))
presentViewController(pincodeAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

My current alert view's text fields are very square and that does't look to well.

What I want:

[image]

What I have:

[image]

Comment: I guess its a bug in the sdk. Maybe you can create a custom alert view?

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out? I'm facing a similar issue.

Comment: No I didn't, I am considering to go with a custom view.

Answer (score 0):

Set your alertViewStyle.

```
alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyle.LoginAndPasswordInput
```

Comment: UIAlertViewStyle is deprecated from iOS9

Comment: what is alternate to UIAlertviewstyle in ios 11

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the border style on the pin code field;

```
            pinCodeTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect
            pinCodeTextField.placeholder = "Password"
            pinCodeTextField.secureTextEntry = true
```

I also had an issue with a black border, if you have the same take a look at this answer;

[UITextField in UIAlertController (border, backgroundColor)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30040963/uitextfield-in-uialertcontroller-border-backgroundcolor/30225592#30225592)