# UITextField in UIAlertController (border, backgroundColor)

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uialertcontroller

Here is a screenshot of a `UIAlertController`. I was just playing around custom fonts and `textfield` properties but I was unable to accomplish the following:

- clear background of the `UITextField`
- no ugly border (black box) as shown below

[image]

As I dived more into the code and iOS runtime headers, I was able to modify border and background color but the above issue still remains as those properties belong to a container `UITextView`. Changing background to `clearColor` doesn't help.

Has anybody ever played around with this? Not sure if I would ever take my app into production with such ugly text fields.

**EDIT (May 13, 15)** The answer below by Rory McKinnel is tested for iOS 8 - 8.3 and works just fine. The result is below:

[image]

Comment: I think you forgot the screenshot.

Comment: Sorry about that. Attached screenshot.

Comment: So ```[textField setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleNone]``` didn't do anything?

Comment: No. As I said, the textfield is less of an issue as it is contained in some other textfields which are not responding to these customizations.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Had some fun with this. The following seems to work. Obviously judging by what was required, it has no future proofing and is a patch away from not working.

I figured this out by walking the view hierarchy in the debugger, from which I noticed a UIVisualEffectView. Removing that seems to give you what you want along with setting the containing view to a clear background. Without removing the visual effect, a clear background shows what is behind the alert view itself for some reason.

```
UIAlertController *alertController = 
 [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Its Not Pretty!" 
                                     message:@"Some times things get ugly!"                          
                              preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

[alertController addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField){
    textField.text = @"Text: No border and clear 8^)";

 }];
[self presentViewController:alertController animated:TRUE completion:^{
}];

for (UIView* textfield in alertController.textfields) {
    UIView *container = textField.superview;
    UIView *effectView = container.superview.subviews[0];

    if (effectView && [effectView class] == [UIVisualEffectView class]){
        container.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [effectView removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! That's true; it might just break in the next patch but that's how life is. Hard. This is exactly what I was looking for. I myself tinkered a lot here but never thought about removing the visual effect view from the view hierarchy.

Comment: Doesn't work with iOS9.1, textField.superview is NULL.

Comment: @Matthew Shame, it was not expected to last the test of time though. Sure your code is right? a text with no superview would imply it is not in the UI? cOuld your text field be null?

Comment: @RoryMcKinnel: the textField is not added yet to the superview at that time, so the superview is NULL. It does work after the completion of presentViewController, but the sudden disappearance of the black border looks glitchy.

Comment: @Matthew Try doing it after you call presentViewController rather than in the completion. After the present call the views should at be in place. Hopefully that should work.

Answer (score 6):

here is the important part in swift:

```
for textfield: UIView in alertController.textfields {
   var container: UIView = textField.superview
   var effectView: UIView = container.superview.subviews[0]
   container.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
   effectView.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Comment: Thanks Bro, this took me 1hr to find.

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 3 clear version**

```
alertController.textFields?.forEach {
    $0.superview?.backgroundColor = .clear
    $0.superview?.superview?.subviews[0].removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this.
As you need only clear color to textfield of your alertview.
simply add lines of code after your alertview is created.

```
 UITextField *textField = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];
 textField.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
 textField.superview.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
```

EDIT 
for alertviewCoontroller you can add

```
[alert addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField) {
        textField.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        textField.superview.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

    }];
```

Thanks, revert if any confusion.

Comment: This is answer is irrelevant when it comes to `UIAlertController`.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the border and background color like this:

```
    let subview = alertController!.view.subviews.first! as UIView
    let alertContentView = subview.subviews.first! as UIView
    alertContentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
    alertContentView.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
    alertContentView.layer.borderWidth = 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift 2.0 version:

```
for textField in alert.textFields! {
    if let container = textField.superview, let effectView = container.superview?.subviews.first where effectView is UIVisualEffectView {
       container.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
       effectView.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To address the situation as discussed in @Rory McKinnel and @Matthew where the superview are NULL and address modifying presented view:

```
extension UIAlertController {
    override open func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
       super.viewWillAppear(animated)
       self.textFields?.forEach {
           $0.superview?.backgroundColor = .color
           $0.superview?.superview?.subviews[0].removeFromSuperview()
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very hacky, so examine it well before using (tested on iOS 8.3):

```
UIAlertController* alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"My Alert"
                                                               message:@"This is an alert."
                                                        preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

[alert addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField) {

    textField.placeholder = @"This is my placeholder";
    textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:246.0/255.0 green:246.0/255.0 blue:246.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]; // You can change it to whatever color you want
    [textField superview].backgroundColor = textField.backgroundColor;
    [[textField superview] superview].backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

}];
```

Comment: This does not seem to work. I want a clear background, i.e. the background color should basically be `clearColor`. This doesn't seem to achieve that.

Comment: Just give it the color of the alert background and it will demonstrate.

Comment: I am not sure that is the requirement here. I just want a textfield that is a clear background, not the background of the alert.