# Custom TextField in UIAlertController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uialertcontroller

I could add a textfield in UIAlertController using

```
UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"message" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
[alertController addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField * _Nonnull textField) {

}];
```

Is there any possibility to add a custom textfield inside an alert controller?

Comment: Custom textfield mean?

Comment: @Krunal A subclassed text field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not think that it's possible to use a `UITextField` subclass in an `UIAlertController`. You can only edit the textfield's properties in the configuration handler.

Answer (score 1):

**No**, you can't. You have to implement custom Alert View for this purpose.
You can try libraries - [ALERT ACTION SHEET LIBRARIES](https://github.com/vsouza/awesome-ios#alert--action-sheet).

Or if you need text field with `UIAlertView` its self with a '*clean*' look - [UITextField in UIAlertController (border, backgroundColor)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30040963/uitextfield-in-uialertcontroller-border-backgroundcolor)