# Space between TextFields in UIAlertController

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I a built a UIAlertController with two text fields. I am wondering how I can some space between them...see screenshot.

Here is my code defining UIAlertController and the my 2 text fields.

```
let alertController: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Property Type", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)

        alertController.view.tintColor = UIColor(displayP3Red: 30.0 / 255.0, green: 53.0 / 255.0, blue: 94.0 / 255.0, alpha: 1.0)

        alertController.addTextField { (textField) -> Void in
            self.propertyTextField = textField
            self.propertyTextField.delegate = self
            self.propertyTextField.placeholder = "Please enter a property type"
        }

        alertController.addTextField { (textField) -> Void in
            self.unitPropertyTextField = textField
            self.unitPropertyTextField.delegate = self
            self.unitPropertyTextField.placeholder = "Please enter a unit number (if applicable)"
        }
```

Here is the screenshot

[image]

Comment: You can't customize the textfields. (duplicate) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45758565/custom-textfield-in-uialertcontroller

Answer (score 0):

You can't customize the textfield placement in Apple's UIAlertController. But you might be interested in using a custom AlertController like [SCAlertView-Swift](https://github.com/vikmeup/SCLAlertView-Swift).

Your other option, if you really desire to have this feature, is to probably make your own version of the UIAlertController