# swift remove TextField borders

Tags: ios, swift, alert, textfield

I have a textField in an alert.
I've configured its borderStyle like that:

```
textField.borderStyle = .roundedRect
```

But there's still another rect border around the first one as you can see:

[image]

I'd like to remove it by code but I don't find any options or what to do it.

Here is the alert code:

```
private func presentUsernameAlert() {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Alors ?", preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.addTextField(configurationHandler: newUsername)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Annuler", style: .default, handler: nil))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Confirmer", style: .default, handler: nil))
    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

private func newUsername(textField: UITextField) {
    usernameTextField = textField
    usernameTextField?.borderStyle = .roundedRect
    usernameTextField?.keyboardAppearance = .dark
    usernameTextField?.placeholder = "Nouveau pseudo"
}
```

then I call `presentUsernameAlert()`

Comment: check if you have `textfield.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor` in some part of your code

Comment: no, I don't have anything like that...

Comment: can you put all the AlertView relevant code in your question?

Comment: Yes no problem, let me two sec

Comment: Apple's controls are usually not very flexible, your options are either write your own version, modify it using private APIs or by going through the subviews (both which can get your app rejected or make it break eventually) or just using it as it is. I suggest you leave it as it is.

Comment: I hope you're wrong because it's not really fancy

Comment: try using this property    `open var textFields: [UITextField]? { get }` of `AlertViewController`, in your case should be index 0 and casting to `UITextField` set his borderWidth = 0

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30040963/uitextfield-in-uialertcontroller-border-backgroundcolor . Borrowing the idea from here, I think you should write `for textField: UIView in alert.textFields! {
            let container: UIView = textField.superview!
            let effectView: UIView = container.superview!.subviews[0]
            container.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
            effectView.removeFromSuperview()
        }`
But call it after you present the alert.

Comment: I tried but I don't understand all of this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using this property `open var textFields: [UITextField]? { get }` of `AlertViewController`, after visual debugging I saw that we need to remove the `superView.superView.subView` in 0, and change the `TextField.superView` background to clear fix the issue.

**Try this code:**

```
private func presentUsernameAlert() {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Alors ?", preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.addTextField(configurationHandler: newUsername)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Annuler", style: .default, handler: nil))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Confirmer", style: .default, handler: nil))
    present(alert, animated: true) {

    }
    if let textFields = alert.textFields {
        if textFields.count > 0{
 textFields[0].superview!.superview!.subviews[0].removeFromSuperview()
            textFields[0].superview!.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        }
    }
}
```

**What it should end up looking like:**

[image: Alert Textfield with Rounded Borders]

Comment: @Placard I am testing I will post something as soon as I have confirmed result