# Removing border around textfield on UIAlertController

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I have a requirement that i need to add textfield on UIAlertController after alert message. I am using below code to achieve above requirement.

```
    *anAlertController.addTextField { (textField) in
        textField.allowsEditingTextAttributes = false
        textField.borderStyle = .none
        textField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        textField.layer.borderWidth = 0.0
        textField.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        textField.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
        textField.delegate = self
        textField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
        textField.text = "123456"
    }*
```

Above code is not removing border around textfield and not matching with alert background color.
But if i try to add textfield to viewcontroller view  with above code it is removing border padding.
What wrong i am doing. Can you please anybody suggest how to achieve that

Comment: Why you have tagged the question as objective-c, while the code written is in swift

Comment: Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30040963/uitextfield-in-uialertcontroller-border-backgroundcolor/30225592

Comment: @MahakMittal Because if anybody knows in objective-c we can convert it to swift

Comment: @MahakMittal above link working properly. i tried it but i was placed above code before presenting the alert. Now i added above code after alert present.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UITextField in UIAlertController (border, backgroundColor)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30040963/uitextfield-in-uialertcontroller-border-backgroundcolor)